# Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04 does not show the webpage properly

Tags: 12.04

How do I make firefox in ubuntu display the website like firefox in Windows?

The settings are exactly the same in both os'.  Thay have the same mscorefonts but somehow, Firefox on Ubuntu displays it's stock Times font instead of what the site requests.

How do I get Firefox on Ubuntu to work to display some pages correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change default fonts in `Edit > Preferences > Content`. In this window you should see `Fonts and colors` heading and `Default font` setting. On the right side of this, you could find `Advanced` button; click it and you'll see the window where you'll be able to change default fonts.